# Jquery tabs MVC avoid duplicate tabs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, model-view-controller, jquery-selectors

i have a series of links when clicked adds tab using jquery.

```
function addTab(title, uri) {
    var newTab = $("#tabs").tabs("add", uri, title);
}
```

I want only one tabs per link. if users keeps pressing the link it keeps adding new tabs to that div.

one way i was thinking was adding a id to anchor that that is created inside the li of the Tab by jquery but i don;t see how to do that so

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#ui-tabs-4"><span>Ncollison Collison</span></a></li>
```

instead of justtab number that jquery gives i want to add id with unique value that i will pass to the method. so this  `<a href="#ui-tabs-4">`  becomes `<a href="#ui-tabs-4"  id="12323">`  so i can check for this id before i add another tab.
i am not sure how to add this unique value to the tab anchor right after i add the tab in method above addTab(title, uri, uniquevlaue) .

**EDIT1**

```
$(function () {

    $('#tabs').tabs(
        { cache: true },
        {
            ajaxOptions: {
                cache: false,
                error: function (xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                    $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab.");
                },
                data: {},
                success: function (data, textStatus) { }
            },
            add: function (event, ui) {
                //select the new tab
                $('#tabs').tabs('select', '#' + ui.panel.id);
            }
        });
});

function addTab(title, uri) {
    // If tab already exist in the list, return
    if ($("#" + title).length != 0)
        return;
    var newTab = $("#tabs").tabs("add", uri, title);
}

function closeTab() {
    var index = getSelectedTabIndex();
    $("#tabs").tabs("remove", index)
}

function getSelectedTabIndex() {
    return $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'selected');
}

function RefershList() {
    $('#frmPeopleList').submit();
}


    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I have links that call this similar to below

```
 <input id="btnAddTab" type="button" onclick="addTab('Add Person','<%= Url.Action("Create", "People")  %>')" value='Add New Person' />
```

**EDIT 2**
Generated HTML

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#ui-tabs-2"><span>Rwestbrook Westbrook</span></a></li><li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#ui-tabs-4"><span>Rwestbrook Westbrook</span></a></li><li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#ui-tabs-6"><span>Rwestbrook Westbrook</span></a></li><li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#ui-tabs-8"><span>Rwestbrook Westbrook</span></a></li><li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#ui-tabs-10"><span>Rwestbrook Westbrook</span></a></li></ul><div id="ui-tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"><h2>Chat</h2>
<input type="text" value=" " id="msg">
<input type="button" value="send" id="send">
<ul id="message">
</ul></div><div id="ui-tabs-4" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"><h2>Chat</h2>
<input type="text" value=" " id="msg">
<input type="button" value="send" id="send">
<ul id="message">
</ul></div><div id="ui-tabs-6" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"><h2>Chat</h2>
<input type="text" value=" " id="msg">
<input type="button" value="send" id="send">
<ul id="message">
</ul></div><div id="ui-tabs-8" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"><h2>Chat</h2>
<input type="text" value=" " id="msg">
<input type="button" value="send" id="send">
<ul id="message">
</ul></div><div id="ui-tabs-10" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"><h2>Chat</h2>
<input type="text" value=" " id="msg">
<input type="button" value="send" id="send">
<ul id="message">
</ul></div>
    <div id="ui-tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"></div><div id="ui-tabs-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"></div><div id="ui-tabs-5" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"></div><div id="ui-tabs-7" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"></div><div id="ui-tabs-9" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"></div></div>
```

URI sent is '/Chat/AddChat

Comment: what r u using jquery UI tab ?? can u post your html codes ??

Comment: found a solution here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632155/how-to-add-the-id-to-dynamically-created-jquery-tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, loop thorugh the tabs, and  check for title if exists ..create

```
function addTab(title, uri) {
   var tabNameExists = false;
  $('#tabs ul li a').each(function(i) {
    if (this.text == title) {
     tabNameExists = true;
    }
  });

 if (!tabNameExist){
    var newTab = $("#tabs").tabs("add", uri, title);
 }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632155/how-to-add-the-id-to-dynamically-created-jquery-tab

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether there is a tab which links to that URL. One way to do it would be:

```
$('a.ui-tabs-anchor[href="' + uri + '"]').length > 0;
```

The .ui-tabs-anchor is the class assigned to the "a" tag for the tab, at least in the current jquery UI version.

-- The previous code was for JQuery-UI 1.9, for 1.8 (and probably previous versions):

```
function urlExists(uri) {
    var exists = false; 
    $.each($('#tabs a'), function() { 
        exists = exists || $(this).data('href.tabs') == uri }
     );
    return exists;
}
```

Comment: I just saw that the HTML generated for your tabs is not the same as the one I get (or the one in http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/tabs/default.html). Could you post an example of the generated HTML for your tabs that includes the link to the URI you pass to addTabs (so that I can try to figure the correct selector for you).

Comment: Added javascript code to check if URI already exists (for your jQuery-UI version). In 1.8 jQuery UI saves the URL for the tab inside the .data() properties of the generated link.