# how to use querySelector to select dynamic added elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dom like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a>test</a></li>
   <li><a>test</a></li>
   <li><a>test</a></li>
   <li><a>test</a></li>
</ul>
```

the `<li>` element are added to the html dynamically so that I cannot add id to it. 
And I'm using css selector to select the `<li>` element by using:

```
document.querySelector("li:nth-child(1)")
```

But how can I select the `<a>` element inside the `<li>`? Can I do a querySelector inside anther querySelector? Or there's some better ways to do it? Thanks.

Comment: `"li:nth-child(1) a"` ?

Comment: [Check this stack post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10632206/3985848)

Comment: do you mean you want to get them in a "live" state? or just after they have been created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But how can I select the `<a>` element inside the `<li>`?

Selector syntax includes [the descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators), which is a space

```
document.querySelector("li:nth-child(1) a")
```

---

> Can I do a querySelector inside anther querySelector?

The `querySelector` method appears on all HTML elements. You can chain them:

```
document.querySelector("li:nth-child(1)").querySelector('a');
```

… which you probably shouldn't in this case.

If you were selecting multiple elements (with `querySelectorAll`) then this would be less viable as you would have to loop over the first set of results and then query the descendants of each one.

Using native selector syntax is usually easier and clearer.

Comment: What does your avatar need a gun for, when you are a ninja :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do a querySelector inside anther querySelector?

**Yes**

```
document.querySelector('li:nth-child(1)').querySelector('a');
```

> Or there's some better ways to do it?

**Yes**

```
document.querySelector('li:nth-child(1) a');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector("li:nth-child(1) a");
```

Will work